# que codigo debo utilizar en ruby para conexiones de datos para un listo general?

Tags: ruby

Soy nueva en ruby.

Tengo un listado de muchas personas que sera utilizado para jornada1 de entrega de beneficios. Ese listado se alimenta de una base de dato ya creada, dicha base de dato creare solo una vista para llamar los datos de las personas que estarán en el listado. Esas personas que esta en este listado pertenecen a la jornada1

Para la segunda jornada2 varias personas de la jornada1 NO quiero que estén en la jornada2 y en la jornada3 personas que están en la jornada1 quiero que estén.

La pregunta es:

¿como hago o cual es el código que debo utilizar en ruby para llamar esos datos de la jornada1 que luego no estarán en la jornada2 pero en la jornada3 si necesito que estén?

OJO manejando siempre el mismo listado que cree desde la jornada1

Comment: Que codigo llevas hasta ahora? Como obtienes, en codigo, ese listado de personas que son parte de la primera jornada?

Comment: Hola, Katherin, no es por ser insistente, pero ¿qué es lo que has hecho? ¿cuál es el código con el cual tienes problemas?. Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda sobre cómo aclarar esta pregunta. Saludos